# How to change $.ajax url source variables on button click?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, var

The script below displays thumbnail images from the gallery1thumbs folder and when clicked opens the larger version from the gallery1full folder.

I want to create a button that when clicked, will change those values to  gallery2thumb gallery2full so that new images display, replacing the old ones.

I have tried so many approaches that all failed.  I am trying to do this as simple as possible as the page will ultimately have a lot of these buttons. I don't want the page to reload which is why I chose ajax.

I just don't know how to code the button so it changes these values and displays the new content.

```
 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
ajaxFunction = function(gallery) {
  $.ajax({
    url : gallery.thumbs,
    success: function (data) {
      $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
            $("#griddie").append( "<a class='item' href='"+ gallery.full + val +"'><img class='squares' src='"+ gallery.thumbs + val +"'></a>" );
        } 
      });
    }
  });
};
gallery = [];
gallery[0] = {
  thumbs: "/gallery1thumbs/",
  full: "/gallery1full/"
}
gallery[1] = {
  thumbs: "/gallery2thumbs/",
  full: "/gallery2full/"
}
counter = 0;
$("#button").click( function() {
 ajaxFunction([counter % 2]);
});
});
</script>
<button id="button">click here</button>
<div id="griddie"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can change those variables on click... but you'll have to re-run the ajax request with the new values.

Comment: yes, that is what I am stuck on. I'm not sure how to code that button to re-run the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple way to do this would be to wrap the AJAX request in a function like this

```
ajaxFunction = function(gallery) {
  $.ajax({
    url : gallery.full,
    success: function (data) {
      $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
            $("#griddie").append( "<a class='item' href='"+ data + val +"'><img class='squares' src='"+ gallery.thumbs + val +"'></a>" );
        } 
      });
    }
  });
};
```

then call that function on button click. then you can make the paths into objects (something like this would work)

```
gallery = [];
gallery[0] = {
  thumbs: "/gallery1thumbs/",
  full: "/gallery1full/"
}
gallery[1] = {
  thumbs: "/gallery2thumbs/",
  full: "/gallery2full/"
}
```

then you can toggle which one you're using, and call your new ajax function like so

```
counter = 0;
$("#button").click( function() {
 ajaxFunction(gallery[counter % 2]);
});
```

edit: forgot to mention, you can probably just save the thumbs somewhere, and if you can memoize all of the resources it’s even better, then you only have to make a call the first two times. good luck!

Comment: Thank you Luke for this fantastic approach! I have updated my original post with the script as you laid out but nothing is happening on page load or on button click.  My folder paths are certainly correct as I've used them earlier.  Perhaps I'm not assembling the elements you have provided properly or something is incorrect?  Also, in the button code, i'm not sure what [counter % 2] means.

Comment: Hey @DC1 , [here's a quick overview of what % does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()), basically, when we have any integer and we perform (n % 2), we will get either 0 or 1, depending on if n is even or odd, respectively.

I left the first jQuery document ready function out. could you maybe try to build this with a remote datasource in codepen.io?

Comment: Hi Luke, I added a quick pen. I couldn't find a public resource of jpgs to add to the pen but it definitely doesn't work, even when I tried the full urls to my folders instead of just /gallery.. here is the pen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjmpzY

Comment: I was able to get things working with your approach. Works great. Thanks so much!